# Shell script to extract data from file between two date ranges

Tags: bash, date, sed, awk, timestamp

I have a huge file, with each line starting with a timestamp as shown below. I need a way to grep lines between two dates. Is there any easy way to do this using sed or awk  instead of extracting out date fields in each line and comparing day/month/year?

example, need to extract data between  2013-06-01  to 2013-06-15 by checking the timestamp in the first field

File contents:

```
2013-06-02T19:44:59;(3305,3308,2338,102116);aaaa;xxxx
2013-06-14T20:01:58;(2338);aaaa;xxxx
2013-06-12T20:01:58;(3305,3308,2338);bbbb;xxxx
2013-06-13T20:01:59;(3305,3308,2338,102116);bbbb;xxxx
2013-06-13T20:02:53;(2338);bbbb;xxxx
2013-06-13T20:02:53;(3305,3308,2338);aaaa2;xxxx
2013-06-13T20:02:54;(3305,3308,2338,102116);aaaa2;xxxx
2013-06-14T20:31:58;(2338);aaaa2;xxxx
2013-06-14T20:31:58;(3305,3308,2338);aaaa;xxxx
2013-06-15T20:31:59;(3305,3308,2338,102116);bbbb;xxxx
2013-06-16T20:32:53;(2338);aaaa;xxxx
2013-06-16T20:32:53;(3305,3308,2338);aaaa2;xxxx
2013-06-16T20:32:54;(3305,3308,2338,102116);bbbb;xxxx
```

Comment: What did you try?  Did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not have been your first choice but Perl is great for this task.

```
perl -ne "print if ( m/2013-06-02/ .. m/2013-06-15/ )" myfile.txt
```

The way this works is that if the first trigger is matched (i.e. `m/2013-06-02/`) then the condition (`print`) will be executed on each line until the second trigger is matched (i.e. `m/2013-06-15`).

However this trick won't work if you specify `m/2013-06-01/` as a trigger because this is never matched in your file.

A less exciting technique is to extract some text from each line and test that:

```
perl -ne 'if ( m/^([0-9-]+)/ ) { $date = $1; print if ( $date ge "2013-06-01" and $date le "2013-06-15" ) }' myfile.txt
```

(Tested both expressions and working).

Comment: @Vijay the first technique will only work if dates are in sorted order. The second technique will work with unsorted data.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The second technique works perfect for my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
awk -F'-|T' '$1==2013 && $2==06 && $3>=01 && $3<=15' hugefile
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this will not meet my complete need, as I will have to modify it further to extract data between different year/month

Comment: @Amogh Sorry, I was not able to understand your complete need from this - _need to extract data between 2013-06-01 to 2013-06-15 by checking the timestamp in the first field_

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to print all lines between two patterns. In this case, you will have to `sort` the file first because the dates are interleaved:

```
$ sort file | sed -n '/2013-06-12/,/2013-06-15/p'
2013-06-12T20:01:58;(3305,3308,2338);bbbb;xxxx
2013-06-13T20:01:59;(3305,3308,2338,102116);bbbb;xxxx
2013-06-13T20:02:53;(2338);bbbb;xxxx
2013-06-13T20:02:53;(3305,3308,2338);aaaa2;xxxx
2013-06-13T20:02:54;(3305,3308,2338,102116);aaaa2;xxxx
2013-06-14T20:01:58;(2338);aaaa;xxxx
2013-06-14T20:31:58;(2338);aaaa2;xxxx
2013-06-14T20:31:58;(3305,3308,2338);aaaa;xxxx
2013-06-15T20:31:59;(3305,3308,2338,102116);bbbb;xxxx
```

Comment: Thanks, but again this may not work if the input date pattern does not exist in the file.

Comment: I think it is very useful to have this answer in case anybody else comes across this question and has sorted data. Thank you!